# Using window function to get how many orders a customer has made so far and when was their last order

Tags: mysql, sql, database, google-bigquery, window-functions

So, this may look like and easy question, but I failed a hiring process because of this one. Let's assume we have the following dataset:

| orderID | clientID | orderDate | orderTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | 2020-10-01 | $100 |
| 2 | 10 | 2020-10-02 | $150 |
| 3 | 12 | 2020-10-04 | $390 |
| 4 | 99 | 2020-11-07 | $99 |
| 5 | 10 | 2020-11-08 | $10 |

I was asked to get the order ID, clientID, order date, how many orders they have made at the time of the order and when was their last order (if it exists). So, in this case, we would end up with:

| orderID | clientID | orderDate | ordersMade | lastOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | 2020-10-01 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 10 | 2020-10-02 | 1 | null |
| 3 | 12 | 2020-10-04 | 1 | null |
| 4 | 99 | 2020-11-07 | 2 | 2020-10-01 |
| 5 | 10 | 2020-11-08 | 2 | 2020-10-02 |

I know window function would help me here, but I still don't know how to use it properly. Could someone help me here please?

Comment: A window function would probably be the preferred method, but it's not obligatory

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `row_number()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by clientId order by orderDate) as ordersmade,
       lag(orderDate) over (partition by clientId order by orderDate) as prev_orderDate
from t;
```